# Conditional button actions depending on selected item in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, if-statement, kotlin

I´m trying to display a message when pressing a button but nothing has been selected in list1. And if an item is selected, I want it to get the listView layout visibility set to gone and the website layout visibility set to visible.

All I get when pressing the button is the toast message no matter what.

Here is the code:

My button:

```
        button1.setOnClickListener {
            var selectedObj = list1.getSelectedItem()
            if (selectedObj == null) {
                toast("You need to choose an item form the list first")
            }
            else {
                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                builder.setTitle("Warning")
                builder.setMessage("This service requires data")
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", { dialogInterface: DialogInterface, i: Int ->
                    ListView.visibility = View.GONE
                    website.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                })
                builder.setNegativeButton("No", { dialogInterface: DialogInterface, i: Int -> })
                builder.show()
            }

        }
```

here is my listView:

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textSize="10dp"

</ListView>
```

my code:

```
    val nameofanimals = arrayOf("cat","dog","parrot")

val list1 = findViewById(R.id.list1) as ListView

internal lateinit var adapteranimals: ArrayAdapter<String>
```

my adapter:

```
adapteranimals = ArrayAdapter(
    this@MainActivity,
    R.layout.list1layout,
    nameofanimals)
list1.adapter = adapteranimals
```

Tyvm in advance for yout support

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

ListView does not store selectedItem position when you set choice mode. It stores the checked item position.

Check this out

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var listView:ListView
internal lateinit var adapteranimals: ArrayAdapter<String>
val nameofanimals = arrayOf("cat","dog","parrot")
private lateinit var btn1:Button
private lateinit var myobject:String

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.list1)
    btn1 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn1)
    adapteranimals = ArrayAdapter(
            this@MainActivity,
            R.layout.list1layout,
            nameofanimals)
    listView.adapter = adapteranimals
    btn1.setOnClickListener {
        val pos = listView.getCheckedItemPosition()
        myobject  = listView.getAdapter().getItem(pos) as String
        Log.d("Selected item",myobject);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Hi and tyvm, where should I add these lines in my code, I´m working with Kotlin in Android btw.

Comment: add this in your button click handler

Comment: I'm totally lost, coz it seems I can not import what is needed since I'm not working in java but in Kotlin, I'm getting the unsolved reference message

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the variable from list and you expect the list to store that variable position. But unfortunately list does not save the click item position. Use this code and the item that is clicked is in position.

```
 ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         // Object listItem = list.getItemAtPosition(position);
            ListView.visibility = View.GONE
            website.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            //you can get the list item clicked in position variable


       } 
    });
```